# No connection with database inside DataGridView wizard

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, named-pipes

I have a problem with connecting the SQL database inside the DataGridView in C#

When I add a DataGridView window and go to the wizard to add a connection. Then there is no database that can be selected.

I selected the Server name and when I select or enter the name of the database I get this error. 
Maybe someone knows what I can do?

Error message:
[image]

My Database:
[image]

@EDIT1:
I checked the Services and restarted them. But that didn't help.
Also when I click on the drop-down menu to select a database it tells me that it's loading the database and after 10 sec the error pops up as above.

I have really no idea what's the problem.

@EDIT 2:

I have uninstalled and deleted everything that had to do with the SQL and SQL server.  I downloaded new SQL server from the Microsoft website, installed it and everything works fine now. I also gave it another name while installing. So not the standard MSSQLSERVER. And now it works.

Tnx everybody for trying to help :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using the full server\instance name in the connection?

Comment: Yes, I just use the DataGridViewDatabase name and the error pops up.. also when I click on Browse..  the error pops up.

Comment: @Mariioo so have you tried the exact name as you have in the Management Studio for the server?

Comment: Check your Sql Server service is running or not?

Comment: @SrustiThakkar  yes the services are running, I added a picture above.

Comment: @BorisSokolov I did, but the same error pops up. Also when I use the drop-down menu to select the database there is nothing to select.

Comment: @Mariioo that's strange. If you are able to connect from the Management Studio - you should be able to connect from Visual Studio as well. Your error is more likely because the server name is wrong. Maybe you have to add your compute name to the full path